# Flutter- Convert JSON to a Quill Delta

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I need to convert *json to quill delta* or *doc/docx to quill delta* format so that I could see the document with **flutter_quill** editor. Or is there any better way to do that so that I could see doc/docx into flutter_quill and edit and Upload it? Ex.

```
{"\ufeffLorem ipsum \n\n\u200b Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc ac faucibus odio."}
```

Quill format.

```
{"ops":[{"insert":"hello, "},{"insert":"world","attributes":{"bold":true}}]}
```

Comment: From quil delta, they told they only supports Quill formats only for now.